# Possible to assign variables based on element in for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
for asset in port_close.columns.drop('P&L'):
    forecasts = {}
    am = arch_model(port_close[asset])
    for i in range(20):
        res = am.fit(first_obs=i, last_obs=i + end_loc, disp='off')
        temp = res.forecast(horizon=1).variance
        fcast = temp.iloc[i + end_loc - 1]
        forecasts[fcast.name] = fcast
    asset+'_vol' = pd.DataFrame(forecasts).T
```

I understand why that last line doesn't work, but in this for loop I want each name "asset" to be assigned to a separate dataframe. The "asset" in the first for loop references the columns `['AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'IBM']`. So I want a dataframe called AAPL_vol and so on. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to dynamically create a variable name, which you can't do, and there isn't really good reason for doing. I suggest alternatively creating a dictionary of `vols` if you will, and assigning something like `AAPL_vol` as the key and the corresponding dataframe as the value.

Comment: don't dynamically create variables, use a *container* like a list or a dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to dynamically create a variable name, which isn't straightforward and there isn't really good reason for doing so. I suggest alternatively creating a dictionary of `vols` and assigning something like `AAPL_vol` as the key and the corresponding dataframe as the value.

Something like this.

```
vols = {}
for asset in port_close.columns.drop('P&L'):
    forecasts = {}
    am = arch_model(port_close[asset])
    for i in range(20):
        res = am.fit(first_obs=i, last_obs=i + end_loc, disp='off')
        temp = res.forecast(horizon=1).variance
        fcast = temp.iloc[i + end_loc - 1]
        forecasts[fcast.name] = fcast
    vols[asset+'_vol'] = pd.DataFrame(forecasts).T
```

Comment: point of order: you *can* dynamically create a named variable, it's just almost always a terrible idea.  :)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this:

`vols = pd.DataFrame() 
for asset in port_close.columns.drop('P&L'):
    forecasts = {}
    am = arch_model(port_close[asset])
    for i in range(20):
        res = am.fit(first_obs=i, last_obs=i + end_loc, disp='off')
        temp = res.forecast(horizon=1).variance
        fcast = temp.iloc[i + end_loc - 1]
        forecasts[fcast.name] = fcast
    vols[asset+'_vol'] = forecasts.values()`